# Conflict between hyperref and multiinclude using beamer class

Tags: beamer, hyperref

I'm working on a presentation using the `beamer` class, and I have the following problem: the hyperlinks created by `hyperref` stop working for any slide placed after a slide that uses the `\multiinclude` command (i.e. any slide placed after the slide "Present approach", in the short example below).

Any ideas of what am I doing wrong?

```
\documentclass[hyperref={pdfpagelabels=false},dvips]{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{textpos}
\usepackage{xmpmulti}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lmodern}    % Use Latin Modern fonts

\usetheme[hideothersubsections]{PaloAlto}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

\subsection{Motivation}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Motivation}
\end{frame}

\subsection{Background}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Background}
\end{frame}

\subsection{Present approach}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Present approach}
  \begin{block}{\centering Approach}
    \begin{figure}
      \centering
      \multiinclude[<+>][format=eps,start=1,end=7,graphics={height=0.55\textheight}]{figs_defense/research_flow_chart}
    \end{figure}
  \end{block}
\end{frame}

\subsection{Contributions}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Contributions}
\end{frame}

\section{Analytical study}

\subsection{General procedure}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Analytical study}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit.

Answer (score 1):

**Workaround:**

If compiled with `pdflatex` (without the `dvips` option) the links are working as they should.

Up to date versions of `pdflatex` will automatically handle the conversion of the included images from `eps` to `pdf`.

---

Off-topic: you don't need `graphicx` or `xcolor` with beamer, as beamer already provides this functionality.